# Error on echo $var "command not found" in bash script

Tags: bash

I was making a small script to get the ip address of the $SSH_CLIENT.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euf -o pipefail
ip=${SSH_CLIENT%% *}
echo $ip
```

I keep getting an error with these two methods:

```bash
ip=echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1}'
```

```bash
 ip=echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}'
```

ERROR:

```bash
$ ./ignoreip.sh
./ignoreip.sh: line 3: the.ip.address.of.ssh_client: command not found
```

-> changed the ip address for obvious reasons.

But it works with :

```bash
ip=${SSH_CLIENT%% *}
```

Can anyone explain to me why the two commands do not work but the last one does ?

Comment: Did you try just a plain `ip=$(echo $SSH_CLIENT)`?

Comment: Did you mean to use Parens, Rogue?

Comment: @PaulHodges whoops, you're right. Been a hot minute since I've bash'd.

Comment: BTW, `set -e` is [generally a bad idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). The default behavior means you need to do a lot of manual error handling, but writing a bunch of error-handling code by hand is far better than enabling `set -e`'s highly version-dependent, [nonportable](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/), and hard-to-predict behavior. (If nothing else, at least browse the "exercises" section of BashFAQ #105 -- the first link in this comment).

Comment: (`set -u` [also has side effects that are often unwanted](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112), but it's much more defensible than `-e` is; nonetheless, I generally recommend static checking for use of unassigned variables with http://shellcheck.net/ as a better practice than `set -u`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your syntax is all wrong. Always try your code at https://www.shellcheck.net/ when something isn't making sense.

```
Line 3:
ip=echo $SSH_CLIENT
^-- SC2209 (warning): Use var=$(command) to assign output (or quote to assign string).
```

What you are doing is assigning `echo` to `ip` for the duration of the command (which then fails) and then attempting to execute the command in `$SSH_CLIENT`, which is apparently `the.ip.address.of.ssh_client`, which is not a valid command.

What you probably want is exactly what you posted at the top, but for purposes of examples...

```
ip=`echo "$SSH_CLIENT" | awk '{ print $1}'`    # old-style backticks
ip=$(echo "$SSH_CLIENT" | awk '{ print $1}')   # nestable bash subcall
```

There are a lot of other possibilities, but one of these is likely the kind of thing you were trying to do. Much better is what you ended up with, though -

```
ip="${SSH_CLIENT% *}"
```

or even

```
ip="${SSH_CLIENT/ */}"
```

Seriously, take the time to read through the whole manual, but especially [Parameter parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), and check out BashFAQ, especially (for this example) his page on [subshells](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell).

Comment: Should probably demonstrate `echo "$SSH_CLIENT"` with the quotes in the awk examples, to avoid guiding folks into the bugs discussed in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)